# How to turn on "Accept remote API calls" in JIRA?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using JIRA in the cloud (so the url I visit is .atlassian.net).

I've been trying to get and create issues using the JIRA API and this library https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home.

However I am getting authorization errors and since I know I have the correct login details, I was wondering if this would be related to the "Accept remote API calls" setting.

I followed the instruction here (https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira063/configuring-jira-options-683542606.html) but I can't see the "Accept remote API calls" setting. I should also mention that I am the account admin.

I'm wondering if this setting is only visible if you are hosting JIRA on your own server, or if there is something else I am missing.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting to enable this on a Cloud instance and the remote API is enabled by default.